# Music theory behind ChordJam

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

Does somebody know the plugin [ChordJam](https://audiomodern.com/shop/plugins/chordjam/)? It`s a nice chord generator Plugin

As you can see, I can choose a scale (C-B), a scale type (Minor, Major, ...) and additionally a ChordType (Major Scale, Minor Scale, Minor9, ...)

I have two questions:

1. I don`t get how scale type and chord type get together. What is e.g. happening, when I choose scale type "Major" and Chord Type "Minor 9"?
2. When I choosed a scale type, I can play the fitting chords on the keys of my keyboard. Example: I choosed C Major and now I can play Cmaj, Dmin ... but when I play C# on keyboard, it plays a Csus4. Why?

Comment: I’m not familiar with ChordJam  but it’s possible that a key outside of the scale will play a common non-diatonic chord For example, Csus4 is a V/IV. There must be an online manual that explains advanced functions.

Comment: Nothing about this in the docs: https://audiomoderns3.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/CHORDJAM/1.5/Chordjam+1.5+User+Manual.pdf - and neither in the full video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDVt62jR5c0

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer from [Audiomodern forum](https://forum.audiomodern.com/t/music-theory-behind-chordjam/1382/2):

> The Chord Type adjusts the chord that is playing and does not make any
> changes in the selected scale. I will try to explain it with the
> example below:
>
> Let’s say that your scale is C Major and your scale type is Major too.
> By pressing the C key, it plays the C-E-G chord as expected.
>
> Now, let’s set the scale type to minor scale. By pressing C, it plays
> C-D-G. Chordjam “tries” to play a minor chord, which typically would
> be C-E♭-G. However, E♭ does not belong to your selected scale which is
> C Major. For this reason, Chordjam brings E♭ to the closest lower note
> that exists in the selected scale (E♭ → D) and it plays C-D-G instead.
>
> To make it play C-E♭-G, you have two options:
>
> - Set the scale type to Chromatic: In this case, Chordjam would play its chords according to the chord types that you have selected.
>
> - Or set the scale type to minor and the chord type to minor too.